# Strange violet icon in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

What does such a violet icon mean in Android Studio?

[image]

It seems to be similar to violet [java cup](https://javabeanz.files.wordpress.com/2009/06/300pxjava_logo-svg.png)...

Which type of class does this icon identify?

Comment: It might be a good idea to describe the icon and where you see it more in words. Then this question is easier to find in the future. It will also be an interesting exercise of your poetic abilities!

Comment: @Lii, I've updated the post :)